# woocommerce free shipping wont work for minimum order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have setup a shipping zone in Canada as the following picture shows

[shipping zone][1]

and i want every order over 70$ in Canada to be get free shipping so i made the free shipping settings as the following image show
[free shipping settings][2]

now when i try to order with an amount over 70$ it does not show the free shipping option to customers.
i also tried to use a free shipping coupon and the free shipping option does not show, any idea what could be the problem
NOTE: it use to work fine with both coupon and minimum amount i just found out about this issue, the website been working fine for a year
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1pof.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0RG2.png

Answer (score -1):

i found the issue for this problem, another plugin that does something to do with shipping for different type for customers had some options disabled and thats why free shipping didnt work, i enabled these options and now its working